# gwt width using columnformatter throwing Invalid Argument

Tags: gwt, gwt2

i am developing a data table using flextable i want to set the width, i did for each cell it is working fine.
Due to preformance concerns i want to move the from cell level to column level, so i used ColumnFormatter but it throwing the

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error): Invalid
>   argument

```
ft.getColumnFormatter().setWidth(col, widths[col] + "px");
```

any guess what is going wrong?

i set table-layout:fixed and border-collapsed for table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035509/gwt-application-throws-javascriptexception-in-ie-only-stack-trace-has-no-help might be of interest.

Comment: The issue is with a column i have to set width to 0 pixels, where GWT is unable to set 0 value as width and throwing the Javascript exception.

For me work around is i set width to table and remaining all columns i set values which sum equal to table width it works, which column i dont want width i skipped setting width so it auto 0 pixels

Thanks Mike Myers for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

```
Invalid argument
```

Let's see  which argument is it:

```
ft.getColumnFormatter().setWidth(col, widths[col] + "px");
```

Here, one of the arguments is `null`.
Most probably `col`.

Check the flow by debugging in `eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that setting the width to zero is the problem.
Changing it to ...

```
if (widths[col] > 0) {    
   ft.getColumnFormatter().setWidth(col, widths[col] + "px");
}
```

solved the problem.

Please note that this **only happens** when using IE11!